# Add multiple vue query builder in same page

Tags: vue.js, query-builder, syncfusion

I need to add multiple 
`<ejs-querybuilder></ejs-querybuilder>`
from https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/documentation/api/query-builder/
In same page
And it didn't work for me
Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for contacting Syncfusion support

We have checked your reported query, we have rendered two querybuilder in same page. Please find the below code snippet:

```
<template>
    <div class="control-section">
        <div class="col-lg-12 querybuilder-control">
            <ejs-querybuilder id="querybuilder" :dataSource="dataSource" :rule="importRules" width="70%">
                <e-columns>
                    <e-column field='EmployeeID' label='Employee ID' type='number' />
                    <e-column field='FirstName' label='First Name' type='string' />
                    <e-column field='TitleOfCourtesy' label='Title Of Courtesy' type='boolean' :values="values" />
                    <e-column field='Title' label='Title' type='string' />
                    <e-column field='HireDate' label='Hire Date' type='date' format='dd/MM/yyyy' />
                    <e-column field='Country' label='Country' type='string' />
                    <e-column field='City' label='City' type='string' />
                </e-columns>
            </ejs-querybuilder>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ejs-querybuilder id="querybuilder1" width="70%">
                <e-columns>
                    <e-column field='EmployeeID' label='Employee ID' type='number' />
                    <e-column field='FirstName' label='First Name' type='string' />
                    <e-column field='TitleOfCourtesy' label='Title Of Courtesy' type='boolean' :values="values" />
                    <e-column field='Title' label='Title' type='string' />
                    <e-column field='HireDate' label='Hire Date' type='date' format='dd/MM/yyyy' />
                    <e-column field='Country' label='Country' type='string' />
                    <e-column field='City' label='City' type='string' />
                </e-columns>
            </ejs-querybuilder>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

For your convenience, we have prepared a sample. Please find the below sample link

Sample link: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-i90tt?file=/src/App.vue:0-1734

Please check the above sample and get back to us if you need further assistance on this.

Regards,

Saranya D